# No client URI found in getBuildTasks() - VSCode - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

On trying to debug a C++ code on VSCode, I am getting the error, "No client URI found in getBuildTasks()"

I am an absolute beginner and am just learning C++ and just set up my VSCode from a tutorial to run C++ on VSCode with minGW-w64. But the debug button just won't work like it should have and is instead throwing that error.

This is what my launch.json looks like:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "echo",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgZCP.png) are the options that show up when I press Run and Debug with a.cpp opened in the folder with the .vscode subfolder containing the aforementioned launch.json file along with c_cpp_properties.json and tasks.json files.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: tha fact that you stillsee the `Run` button means you haven't configured VSC correct. If `launch.json` is found you see a dropdown box with the configs found. What is the `echo` task, surely not a compile task

Comment: @rioV8 I don't understand what you mean by "What is the echo task"

Comment: your `preLaunchTask` is `echo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the Folder that you're working in, into the Workspace.

To do this, select Explorer from the left side bar and click on the big blue **Open Folder** button over there and open the Folder that you're working on and containing the .vscode subfolder.

.

.

*The Desktop is where I build most of my smaller, quicker programs at. I removed the Desktop from the WorkSpace open, in order to stop the Source Control from suggesting me to commit changes to GitHub and hence VSCode had no directory to find the .vscode folder from. This never was a problem when I would debug and run python files but for C++ it was.*

*It was an absolute nooby dumbo mistake of mine but it literally took me 2 days to figure out and I've written the answer down, hoping it helps some other noob. :)*